# Distribution of shift covering

Tags: work-environment

Let’s say a coworker takes a day off on saturday. That coworker starts at 1pm- 9:30pm and I start at 7am-4pm. My boss told me I had to come in at 1pm, which is closing shift. I told him it’s fine i can cover , but he always makes me cover whenever there is a similar scenario. Can my boss pick me to cover shifts everytime? I hate it because its not fair for me. My department has like 15 other coworkers and there’s plenty of other workers who are able to cover, but its me in the end.

Comment: Is that coworker taking a day off on Saturday for a funeral? Seems to be a repeat question - read something similar already...

Comment: Does your contract state the exact start & finish time in it? Is he 'asking' you or 'telling' you? Could you not refuse on the grounds that there is a personal matter you have arranged during the time outside of work?  Have you ever told him that you can't cover? What would you think would be the result if you did refuse?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a law site and there likely are local laws that impact this, but... presuming you are in the US...

Yes, they can require you to pick up the extra shifts or switch shifts. They either pick you because they like your work ethic, they want you to quit, or because you are the only one that says “yes”. You are in a better position to know which than us.

As far as what to do, either you keep telling them yes, start telling them no, or find another job. I recommend looking for another job if you decide to start telling them no.